# How to get Signature level Permission?

Tags: android, signature

I have been looking around for 1 weeks to be able to successed my android app which is android remote controller.

Teamviewer and LogMeIn asks to download their BRAND BASED ADD-ON. These add-ons allowed to get signature level permission?

Is there any way to sign an app with brand-based system certificate.

And can we exactly say that these applications does the job in that way?

Thanks for your helps!

Comment: "These add-ons allowed to get signature level permission?" -- if they are signed with the firmware's signing key, presumably by the device manufacturer, yes. "Is there any way to sign an app with brand-based system certificate" -- sign a licensing deal with the brand in question.

Comment: Teamviewer and others signing a licensing deal?

Comment: AFAIK, yes. They certainly describe themselves as having "partnered" with device manufacturers, and that usually involves some sort of licensing deal.